# .htaccess rewrite from subdirectory of domain to subdirectory of different domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, I've found a few threads pertaining to very similar issues, but haven't had any luck using the answers provided for my own site. Basically I have 2 sites, mapped like this:

```
/public_html/ - points to main domain (www.site1.com)
/public_html/site2.com - points to secondary domain (www.site2.com)
/public_html/portal - points to my target subdirectory
```

I'm trying to get all requests to www.site2.com/portal to load www.site1.com/portal transparently, that is I still want www.site2.com/portal to show in the address bar.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/portal/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /portal/$1 [L]
```

doesn't work at all

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/portal/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site1.com/portal/$1 [L]
```

takes me to http://site1.com/portal/site2.com/portal.

I've been beating my head against a wall over this for a couple days, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Ok, #anubhava obviously has the solution I need, if I take his first solution and change the proxy flag to a redirect flag it works perfectly, so apparently this is a server configuration issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current setup is not going to support what you are trying to get unless you enable mod_proxy in your httpd.conf. So here are 2 options available with you:

#### Option 1: Enable mod_proxy and retain current directory structure

Put this code in your `.htaccess` under `public_html/site2.com` directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(portal/.*)$ http://site1.com/$1 [L,NC,P]
```

#### Option 2: Retain current directory structure and create a symbolic link like this:

```
/path-to/public_html/site2.com/portal -> /path-to/public_html/portal
```

Then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `public_html/site2.com` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

IMHO option # 2 is going to be much easier for you since it just requires creating one symbolic link (I believe you are using some flavor of `*nix`.

Comment: unfortunately the clients sites are on a shared host and I currently don't have shell access (required for symlinks if I'm not mistaken). I have mod_proxy, but example 1 throws a 404. Thanks for this though, it gives me a new place to start testing;) - EDIT: I forgot to turn on the rewrite engine in the first test, now I'm getting a 400 error

Comment: Can you pls check your error.log for the matching log statement on this 400 error.

Comment: the error logs that I have available only log 300 errors:( I'm trying to fix that now

Comment: Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.  
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.  
X-Forwarded-Server

Comment: that's what I see in the browser

Comment: Well in that case mod_proxy is not enabled in your Apache. Changing `P` to `R` will fix this error (of course then your URL in browser will also change). If you check `phpinfo()` output it should show you loaded Apache modules, check whether you get mod_proxy there or not.

Comment: no dice. The host claims to have enabled it by default, but there is no apache config info in the phpinfo()

Comment: at any rate the issue clearly seems to be with my host rather than the snippet. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Ya unfortunately that doesn't help much. About option #2: You can probably create a symbolic link from cpanel or some file manager you have access to.

Comment: hmmm, based on what I've seen so far I doubt I have access, I'll look around though. I'm on hold to talk to their tech support, this client has a long standing account with them so hopefully they can enabled the required modules for me